# count of the array gives wrong value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to `php` and its developing . I declared php array:

```
<?php

     $chk_group[] =array(
         '1' => 'red',
         '2' => 'thi',
         '3' => 'aaa',
         '4' => 'bbb',
         '5' => 'ccc'      
     );

     var_dump($chk_group);

     //continue for loop
     for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($chk_group); $i++) {
         echo count($chk_group);
     }

 ?>
```

here i'm getting `count = 1`  please help me to get count of array.

Comment: In using `$chk_group[] = array(...)` rather than `$chk_group = array(...)`, you've made `$chk_group` a multi-dimensional array, with a single entry at the top level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a multi dimentional array by your this assigment

```
$chk_group[] = array(
         '1' => 'red',
         '2' => 'thi',
         '3' => 'aaa',
         '4' => 'bbb',
         '5' => 'ccc' 
     );
```

can you try without the brackets as :

```
$chk_group = array(
         '1' => 'red',
         '2' => 'thi',
         '3' => 'aaa',
         '4' => 'bbb',
         '5' => 'ccc' 
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$chk_group[]` to `$chk_group` in your first line.

In PHP syntax, `$chk_group[] =` means push the right had value to an array called `$chk_group`.  Your entire array is being stored to `$chk_group[0]`

What you need instead is:

```
 $chk_group[] =array(
     '1' => 'red',
     '2' => 'thi',
     '3' => 'aaa',
     '4' => 'bbb',
     '5' => 'ccc' 
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
count($chk_group[0]);
```

or

```
$chk_group =array('1' => 'red',
                           '2' => 'thi',
         '3' => 'aaa',
         '4' => 'bbb',
         '5' => 'ccc' 



     );

 count($chk_group);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answers, you need to remove the extra `[]` sign, so that assignment in front of the `=` sign, is recognized as the variable. **With this syntax, you say that first element of your array, is another array**.